# Issues installing gearman on MAMP running OS X 10.8

Tags: php, macos, terminal, mamp, gearman

As the title states I am having some issues when installing gearman for PHP in a MAMP environment. Here's what I've done so far:

I've downloaded the latest PECL version and run these commands based on the [docs](http://www.gearman.org/getting_started):

```
tar xzf gearman-X.Y.tgz
cd gearman-X.Y
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

I get to the `phpize` step and receive the error `configure: error: Please install libgearman`

I'm very new to Mac products, terminal/command line execution, etc. Can anyone help me work this? I can't really find any help on the issue when Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile gearman daemon even if you are not running gearman on that machine. That will provide libgearman which you will use for the pecl gearman extension.

You can get gearman here: https://launchpad.net/gearmand/

Comment: Yeah I noticed I skipped the important part by accident. I'm going through a guide on how to install on Mac...hopefully all goes well.